# Using URL routing with querystring parameter cause error to load all .png/.jpg images In ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, routes

I am trying to implement **URL routing** to my web application.
When I implement this to a page which has no `QueryStrings`, it’s working fine.

But when I try to implement the same for a web page which using querystrings its giving Jscript runtime error. and images not found

So  for **JS** i solved like this using `ResolveClientUrl`

```
<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/raphl_map/raphael-min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now in my Ajax call i am dynamically generate img tag with respective urlpath and facing problem for those dynamically images ,

**On ajax success response** am adding li element using for loop

```
var elAdd = "<li class=" + id_setClass + " > <img  src="+photo_src+"/></li>";
$("#ul_itemlist").append(elAdd);
```

**Global.asax**

```
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
      {
        //  routes.Ignore("{file}.png");
        //  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.png");
        // routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpe?g" });
        // routes.Ignore("{*allpng}", new { allpng = @".*\.png(/.*)?" });
        routes.Add(new Route(@".*\.png", new StopRoutingHandler()));
        routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;

         routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "Home", "~/homepage.aspx");
         routes.MapPageRoute("Login", "Login", "~/Login.aspx");
         routes.MapPageRoute("Profile", "Profile/{user_id}", "~/MyProfile.aspx");
       }

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
 }
```

Things i tried which not worked for me are

```
routes.Ignore("{*allpng}", new { allpng = @".*\.png(/.*)?" });
routes.Add(new Route(@".*\.png", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Comment: Are the images generated on the fly or files in the filesystem? For later one you can tell IIS to handle that request and return the file directly. Maybe also take a look at this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx/

Comment: @chrfin: all the images are stored in a folder name as `Images` and path is save in database, so in ajax call i get the imgpath from  database and bind to img tag which i generate dynamically as i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*png}", new { png = @"(.*/)?.*\.png(/.*)?"});
```

This should exclude an route containing `.png` in it (in any directory - thats the point you forgot IMO).

Comment: IgnoreRoute gives error `CS1061: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'IgnoreRoute' and no extension method 'IgnoreRoute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Maybe this only works with MVC. Can you try adding the MVC NuGet package just to check if it works then?

Comment: no its still not working, assembly classes, is there any another without adding MVC

Comment: Sorry, then I have no additional ideas except telling IIS to not even route "real files" to ASP.NET, but return them directly...

Comment: Thanks for your effort, well i try some more hope soon got solved this without using MVC